# GET response from HTTP in WP8 with specific request

Tags: c#, http, windows-phone-8, coordinates

I want the locations of a restaurant and have this GET request:

```
GET /webservices/js-storelocator/wsvclocator.asmx/GetLocations?location=string&biasingPoint=string&targetCountry=string&searchDistance=string&ConsumerData=string&currentPage=string&resultsPerPage=string&longLat=string&metricOption=string&mapFilters=string HTTP/1.1
Host: www.subway.com
```

But I don't know how to implement a HTTP Get request in my WP8 App. I found many solutions, but this get request delivers the geolocation data of the restaurants. And how can I read this data from the response of this Get request? And whats are all those parameters in this GET request?
Thanks in advance for help and for correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the information is information for the server. You can read a Get response easy, follow this example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pakistan/archive/2013/06/14/getting-started-with-web-requests-amp-json-in-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: Tutorial sounds very good, I test it. But with this get request I give some parameters to the server, but I don't know whats mean with "mapFilters" or "metricOption" or "longLat", if I know what I should set in these parameters I know how to build it.

Comment: I am sorry this is specific for the server. But Ideas for me is like google so mapFilters COULD be street, satelite and so on. metricOption Si units or American. longlat, that would be latitude. But again it is specific commands, and cant really say anything other than guess. If I helped A vote is good show of appreciation ;)